# r Knitting error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: 'origin' must be supplied

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am getting this error only when knitting. I have fully cleared my environment and ran it with no errors interactively. Here are the lines of code where the issue comes from:

```
###########################################
# Process the data
###########################################

#Convert factors to string, create a ymd format
df_cer<- data.frame(lapply(df_cer, as.character),stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
   mutate(date = paste0(year(EOM),"-",month(EOM),"-","01"),cer=as.numeric(TotalInstalledMW) ) %>% 
  select(State,date,cer)

# Create ymd format from year and quarter columns
df_aemo <- df_aemo %>% mutate(date = 
                                     ifelse(qtr==1,ymd(paste0(as.character(yr),"-","1","-","01")),
                                            ifelse(qtr==2,ymd(paste0(as.character(yr),"-","4","-","01")),
                                                   ifelse(qtr=="3",ymd(paste0(as.character(yr),"-","7","-","01")),
                                                          ymd(paste0(as.character(yr),"-","10","-","01")))))
                              ) %>%  
  select(date,regionid,avgMW) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.character(as.Date(date))) %>% 
  rename(region = regionid, aemo = avgMW) %>% 
  group_by(date,region) %>% 
  summarise(aemo = mean(aemo))

# Calculate lwp and lwtw 
df <- df_load %>% select(QUARTER,REGION_ID1,PROBMWH,FLOATING,SWAPPRICE,CAPPRICE) %>% 
  arrange(QUARTER) %>% 
  rename(quarter = QUARTER,region=REGION_ID1,mwh=PROBMWH,price=FLOATING,swap=SWAPPRICE,cap=CAPPRICE) %>% 
  mutate(lwp=price/mwh,lwtw=lwp/swap, quarter = as.character(quarter),swaplesscap = swap-cap)

# clean data from over under 300
df_new <- df_load_new %>% mutate(QUARTER = 
                                     ifelse(qtr==1,ymd(paste0(as.character(yr),"-","1","-","01")),
                                            ifelse(qtr==2,ymd(paste0(as.character(yr),"-","4","-","01")),
                                                   ifelse(qtr=="3",ymd(paste0(as.character(yr),"-","7","-","01")),
                                                          ymd(paste0(as.character(yr),"-","10","-","01")))))
                              )%>%  
  select(QUARTER,regionid,LWTWabove300ver1,LWTWbelow300ver1,LWTWabove300ver2,LWTWbelow300ver2) %>% 
  mutate(QUARTER = as.character(as.Date(QUARTER))) %>% 
  rename(quarter=QUARTER, region = regionid)
df_new[is.na(df_new)] <- 0


 df_joined <- df %>% left_join(df_aemo,by=c("quarter"="date","region"))
df_joined <- df_joined %>% mutate(
  swapCapRatio = cap/swap,
  q23Dummy = ifelse(month(quarter)==4|month(quarter)==7,1,0)
)

df_joined<- df_joined %>% 
  left_join(df_new, by=c("quarter","region"))
```

If anyone can spot what is going wrong i'd be very grateful

Comment: Try to replace `mutate(date = as.character(as.Date(date))) %>% ...` with `mutate(date = as.character(as.Date(date,  origin = "1970-01-01"))) %>%...`

Comment: Yes that solved the issue. I had to add that to all my as.Date( ) references.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I had to add origin = "1970-01-01" inside as.Date( )

Comment: Wellcome to stackowerflow. Well done.